# PCA on word2vec embeddings using pre existing model

Tags: python, nlp, jupyter-notebook, pca, word-embedding

I have a word2vec model trained on Tweets. I also have a list of words, and I need to get the embeddings from the words, compute the first two principal components, and plot each word on a 2 dimensional space.

I'm trying to follow tutorials such as this one: https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-word-embeddings-python-gensim/

However in all such tutorials, they create a model based on a random sentence they use and then calculate PCA on all the words in the model. I don't want to do that, I only want to calculate and plot specific words. How can I use the model that I already have, which has thousands of words, and compute the first two principal components for a set list of words I have (around 20)?

So like in the link above, they have "model" with only the words from the sentence they wrote. And then they do "X = model[model.wv.vocab]", then "pca.fit_transform(X)". If I were to copy this code, I would do a PCA on the huge model, which I don't want to do. I just want to extract the embeddings of some words from that model and then compute PCA on those few words. Hopefully this makes sense, thanks in advance. Please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a collection with the same structure (a dictionary) as

```
model.wv.vocab,
```

fill it with your target words, and compute PCA.

You can do this using the following code:

```
my_vocab = {}
for w in my_words:
    my_vocab[w] = model.vw.vocab[w]

X = model[my_vocab]
pca.fit_transform(X)
```

Comment: Thank you! I realize this is a super basic question, sorry, I'm new to word2vec and just learning as I'm going. So my model is called twitter_model, if I just do

`X = twitter_model['word1', 'word2', etc]`
`pca.fit_transform(X)` 

that should work? Is that what you mean by creating a collection or does that need to be a separate step?

Comment: @curlypie99 No, unfortunately, the collection I mentioned should specifically be a dictionary mapping words to Vocab entries (a special gensim datatype). Using the provided code should produce expected results.

Comment: @curlypie99 You are very welcome, good luck with your research (y)

Comment: @CaptainTrojan: Don't we need to do a `normalization` step before feeding the embeddings to **PCA**?

Comment: @aspiring1 If you normalize the word vectors, they will lose a part of their meaning. Scale matters here. If you were to normalize them, some words, which were distant, may appear close to each other. You only want to normalize your data before PCA when you're sure the individual variables have different scales, such as for house prices and house sizes for example, but word vectors are not like that. All dimensions matter equally.